# How prevent calling same api in different components in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working large reactjs application,In that application so many components are there and so many api services also there.
My problem is how to prevent calling same api in different components.
Actually i want to call api one time then ,i will use that api response entire application ,so that we can prevent calling same api in different components.
So please give me any solution.
check the below demo code:

```
enter code here

`FirstComponent:
 ——————————————
 Class FirstComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 this.setState={}
}
componentDidMount() {
this.props.dispatch(getById(1)); //here first time I am calling api
}
render(){
return(
———HTML Code HERE———
)
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    registrationData: state.RegistrationDemand.registrationData 
    // here I am getting response through redux reducer store
    };
};
export default compose(
  translate,
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(FirstComponent);

SecondComponent:
——————————————
Class SecondComponent extends Component {
constructor(props){
this.setState={}
}
componentDidMount() {
this.props.dispatch(getById(1));   //here I need to prevent this second time api calling
}
render(){
return(
———HTML Code HERE———
)
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    registrationData: state.RegistrationDemand.registrationData 
//without calling second component,If I use this one first time when I redirect to this page data is coming hereabout when I refresh second time it is getting null.
    };
};
export default compose(
  translate,
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(SecondComponent);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call the API once your application is mounted. Usually this is done via `componentDidMount` or if you're using hooks, you can add it inside `useEffect`.

And you can just pass down props.

A more better solution is to use `redux` to your project, wherein the whole state of your application is inside a store in which you can connect using `react-redux`.

Comment: Hi Rem,I am already using react-redux in my project,and also using store,but here what I am getting issue is: let explain, first component api service is calling that service response also storing in store i am using that store data by using mapStateToProps function,that is completely okay for me,but when I redirect to second component first time that previous redux store returning the api response but when refresh the page second time it is getting null.

Comment: Can I see a bit of your code so that I can review it properly?

Comment: @AshokSudagani what do you mean `but when refresh the page second time it is getting null.`? If you refresh your browser tab, it means that your js code inits again, and your data which stored in memory cleaned.

Comment: Hi Guys,Please review the above demo code,May be i have made any mistakes

Comment: @AshokSudagani How do you mount those two components? If you are unmounting the FirstComponent before displaying the SecondComponent, and you refresh your tab, for sure it will clean the memory. 

I think what you need is a container that will wrap those two components. It doesn't matter if you unmount any of the two, as long as you keep your container mounted.